# swift черные линии при показе vc

Tags: swift

У меня такая стуктура : [Navigation Controller] -> [UITabBarController] -> [VC]

```
let viewcontroller =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "coVC")
    cotViewcontroller.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Rj", image: UIImage(named: "tab1"), selectedImage: nil)

let tabbarController = CircleBarController()
tabbarController.viewControllers = [viewcontroller, ...]
tabbarController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
let tabnavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabbarController)
tabnavigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(tabnavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

проблема в том, что в самом vc получаю черные линии, как можно их убрать ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для начала попробуйте посмотреть как это выглядит в `Debug View Hierarchy` в икскоде, возможно удастся увидеть какое вью дает эти линии

Comment: @schmidt9 да, спасибо, помогло